# Access row value in template_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)

Tags: theming, 8

In `template_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)`, when I print `$variables['row']`, I get the following object.

[image]

How can I access `values` inside the node entity?

I tried with the following code, but it is not working.

```
$variables['row']->_entity->values['field_file_pdf_upload']->target_id
```

Answer (score 2):

`values` is protected, so you have to use the `get()` method:

```
$variables['row']->_entity->get('field_file_pdf_upload')->target_id;
```

For the field object this shortcut is available (this is not standard OOP and works for fields only):

```
$variables['row']->_entity->field_file_pdf_upload->target_id;
```