# How do get a value from field in if/else statement

Tags: views, entities

In a custom **views-view-fields.html.twig** I do print a list field (field_status) without issues. The values are:

new|New

old|Old

But if i want to do an if/else statement for printing different div containers i do get always printed the div container from else. Does anybody have an idea what i am doing wrong? I tried it too with module Twig Field Value, but i do have the same issues.

```
<div class="card h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
        {% if fields.field_status.content == 'new' %} // |striptags , |raw or a capital value e.g. New do not work , Twig Field Value also do not work: content.field_status|field_value
            <div class="icon medium">
                NEW
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="icon medium">
                OLD
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ fields.title.content }}</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare the left part of the field list you need the raw database value from the entity.

You find the entity in the `row` variable of **views-view-fields.html.twig** :

```
{% if row._entity.field_status.value == 'new' %}
```

See [Access row value in template_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239240/access-row-value-in-template-preprocess-views-view-fieldsvariables)

Comment: You´re great, thanks a lot! Now it works without issues. I´ve spend hours and hours to find a solution.